# Is the tangent line of the function correct anwer?

Tags: calculus

in Calculus homework is given such problem:

> On the planet Quirk, a cell phone tower is a 100-foot pole on top of a
>   green mound 1000 feet tall whose outline is described by the parabolic
>   equation y = 1000 − x^2 . An ant climbs up the mound starting from
>   ground level (y = 0). At what height y does the ant begin to see the
>   tower?

Is the solution of this problem to calculate tangent line of 1000 - x^2 at x = 0 ?

Comment: You want to find the point on the parabola where the tangent line will pass through the point at the top of the tower.

Answer (score 2):

No. You want to find the ($y$-coordinate of) the point at which that tangent has a $y$-intercept of $1100$. The top of the pole is at an altitude of $1100$ feet since it is $100$ feet high and sits on a hill that is already $1000$ feet high.